# dplyr mutate with qdap:synonmyms giving Error: wrong result size

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's a 1 column df with 2 rows:

```
x <- data.frame(a = c("crash", "parking"))
> x
        a
1   crash
2 parking
```

I want to add a new field with the synonmyms of each x in a new column syns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(qdap)
x <-  x %>%
  mutate(syns = synonyms(a, return.list = F, report.null = T))
```

Gives

> ```
> no match for the following:
>
> parking
> ========================
>
> Error: wrong result size (75), expected 2 or 1
> ```

If I run:

```
> synonyms("crash", return.list = F)
```

I get:

```
 [1] "bang"                "boom"                "clang"               "clash"              
 [5] "clatter"             "clattering"          "din"                 "racket"             
 [9] "smash"               "smashing"            "thunder"             "break"              
[13] "break up"            "dash to pieces"      "disintegrate"        "fracture"           
[17] "fragment"            "shatter"             "shiver"              "splinter"           
[21] "dash"                "fall"                "fall headlong"       "give way"           
[25] "hurtle"              "lurch"               "overbalance"         "pitch"              
[29] "plunge"              "precipitate oneself" "sprawl"              "topple"             
[33] "bump (into)"         "collide"             "crash-land"          "drive into"         
[37] "have an accident"    "hit"                 "hurtle into"         "plough into"        
[41] "run together"        "wreck"               "accident"            "bump"               
[45] "collision"           "jar"                 "jolt"                "pile-up"            
[49] "prang"               "smash-up"            "thud"                "thump"              
[53] "bankruptcy"          "collapse"            "debacle"             "depression"         
[57] "downfall"            "failure"             "ruin"                "be ruined"          
[61] "fail"                "fold"                "fold up"             "go belly up"        
[65] "go broke"            "go bust"             "go to the wall"      "go under"           
[69] "emergency"           "immediate"           "intensive"           "round-the-clock"    
[73] "speeded-up"          "telescoped"          "urgent"
```

I can see 75 returned synomns so it looks like my code is trying to add a row for each synomn, whereas I want the vector, in this case with 75 words, added to a single row alongside crash in column a.

How would I do this?

Put another way I want to add an entire chr vector to a single cell within a df

Comment: If the number of elements returned are greater than the number of input, then you may need `do` i.e. `x %>% do(data.frame(syns = synonyms(.$a, return.list = FALSE, report.null = TRUE)))`

Comment: Hi @akrun how would that look? My goal is to end up with a 2 column 2 row data frame, where in this case x[1,2] would be the character vector with the 75 words

Comment: If that is the case,try `x %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(syns = list(synonyms(a, return.list = F, report.null = T)))`

Comment: That got me a step further, thanks. x$syns is a list when looking at str. Can I make this a type chr?

Comment: It would be better to have it in a `list` rather than as `character` strings as any time you can do `%>% unnest` to get the vector.  If you need a string `x %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(syns = toString(synonyms(a, return.list = FALSE, report.null = TRUE)))`

Comment: OK got it, thank you very much. I'll keep it as a list till I finish my preprocessing, then change to a chr only at the end of my chain of ops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
x %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(syns = list(synonyms(a, return.list = FALSE, report.null = TRUE)))
```